# Sexualisation of typical actions and why it is impermissible

Tags: muslim-practices, zina

Actions such as a handshake, high five, looking at the decor hand of a woman can be done without lust. It is hard for me to understand why it is haram because I can’t seem to grasp how one can possible look at ones hand in a lustful manner and somehow fall into Zina. Also things like high fives, there is no haram in such an action (or so it seems if anyone can prove otherwise please do so) is such a simple action that one can do without lust. Looking at the hand of the opposite gender or even a decried hand of an opposite gender most likely will not lead to Zina and I can’t seem to understand why such minor actions are haram. I can’t seem to understand how such things have been sexualised and why it is haram please can someone explain and show Hadith?

Comment: You are confused, those aren't forbidden because they are lustful in nature. They are forbidden because they lead to closeness between men and women which may lead to Zina.

Comment: How does one become close in nature through a simple high five? What about asexual people?